# Symbol not found: _libintl_gettext

Tags: c++, macos, node.js, gettext, dyld

I am trying to create a NodeJS module using C++ and `node-gyp`. The package depends on GNU's Gettext library. I am currently using Mac OS X Mountain Lion. I have tried installing the package myself via manual efforts, via Homebrew, and even via Fink.

The program works via Terminal.app and the package compiles. I can use the `.node` module just fine, except until I use a method in the library that uses `gettext`. I get the following errors in REPL and then REPL exits.

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _libintl_gettext
  Referenced from: /Users/KevinMartin/Dropbox/www/node-locale/build/Release/locale.node
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

dyld: Symbol not found: _libintl_gettext
  Referenced from: /Users/KevinMartin/Dropbox/www/node-locale/build/Release/locale.node
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure if you found the solution, may be libedit can provide the symbols.

Comment: @Vishal This didn't work for me. libintl has become my worst nightmare over the past few days.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably happening because you are not listing `libintl` as a library to be dynamically linked. You need to add something like:

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "...",
      "sources": ["..."],
      "libraries": ["/path/to/gettext/lib/libintl.a"]
    }
}
```

to your binding.gyp file. `libintl` isn't being linked in your app, statically or dynamically, that is why you get the symbol error.

Edit:

You can probably also do something like:

```
{
    "targets": [{
        "target_name": "...",
        "sources": [
            "..."
        ],
        "link_settings": {
             "libraries": ["libintl.8.dylib"]
        }
     }]
}
```